# Why ListView with custom adapter showing nothing?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am absolute beginner to Android Studio. I am now learning about list view. When I use list view with just simple array adapter. It is showing fine. Now I am trying to create a custom adapter with custom row layout.

But when I run the app, it is not throwing error. But activity is showing nothing on the screen. I just got the blank screen and no data is bind to list view. What is wrong with my code?

This is my activity class

```
public class CustomAdapterActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_adapter);

        ListItem item_1 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Name = "Name 1";
        item_1.Email = "Email 1";
        item_1.Phone = "Phone 1";

        ListItem item_2 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Name = "Name 2";
        item_1.Email = "Email 2";
        item_1.Phone = "Phone 2";

        ListItem item_3 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Name = "Name 3";
        item_1.Email = "Email 3";
        item_1.Phone = "Phone 3";

        ListItem item_4 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Name = "Name 4";
        item_1.Email = "Email 4";
        item_1.Phone = "Phone 4";

        ListItem[] items = { item_1 , item_2,item_3 , item_4 };

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this,R.layout.custom_row,items);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is my row model class named ListItem

```
public class ListItem {

    public String Name;
    public String Email;
    public String Phone;

}
```

This is main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout for row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/row_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_name"
        android:id="@+id/row_email"
        android:text="email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_email"
        android:id="@+id/row_phone"
        android:text="phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my custom adapter class.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ListItem[] values;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context,ListItem[] values)
    {
        super(context,-1,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        TextView name_tf = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
        TextView email_tf = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_email);
        TextView phone_tf = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_phone);
        name_tf.setText(values[position].Name);
        email_tf.setText(values[position].Email);
        phone_tf.setText(values[position].Phone);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

No data is bind to ListView while I run the app.

Then I followed to Sankar V answer. It worked. But it still has a slight problem like in image

[image]

Why only item_4 is bind to listview?

Comment: The problem you are creating 4 different objects but setting value for only item_1 which gets replaced every time and last item data is displayed.

Comment: How should I modify it ? I think I am setting value for every row. For example like name_tf.setText(values[position].Name) . How can I get it correct ?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` version of onCreate method instead of `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`

The later is available only in Lollipop and above.

And also create instance of `MyCustomAdapter` instead of Generic `ArrayAdapter`.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter<ListItem>(this,R.layout.custom_row,items);
```

Set data properly. You are creating 4 different objects but setting values for only first object. Change it like below

```
        ListItem item_1 = new ListItem();
        item_1.Name = "Name 1";
        item_1.Email = "Email 1";
        item_1.Phone = "Phone 1";

        ListItem item_2 = new ListItem();
        item_2.Name = "Name 2"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_2
        item_2.Email = "Email 2"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_2
        item_2.Phone = "Phone 2"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_2

        ListItem item_3 = new ListItem();
        item_3.Name = "Name 3"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_3
        item_3.Email = "Email 3"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_3
        item_3.Phone = "Phone 3"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_3

        ListItem item_4 = new ListItem();
        item_4.Name = "Name 4"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_4
        item_4.Email = "Email 4"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_4
        item_4.Phone = "Phone 4"; // This need to be changed from item_1 to item_4
```

Comment: is it working after creating the instance using MyCustomAdapter? Can you please add the logcat?

Comment: Yes. It works. But having problem. I will post the screen shot. Only the item_4 data is bind to listview.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Sorry, I was so urgent with copy-paste effort for second issue. Thanks so much. It worked.